How to resolve Firebase Scheduled Function Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION
Coming back to this error 2 months later:
We have a scheduled function (scheduledFunction) that calls another function (_clearOldReports) that uses a collectionGroup to regularly delete documents from any collection named reports.
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 30 minutes")
  .onRun(async () => {
    return Promise.all([_clearOldDocuments()]);
  });

async function _clearOldDocuments() {
  const date = Date.now() - 600000; // 10 min
  const reports = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collectionGroup("reports")
    .where("generateDate", "<", date)
    .get();
  const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
  reports.forEach((d) => batch.delete(d.ref));
  await batch.commit();
}

In the GCP console logs viewer we are getting Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION but no further details that are useful for troubleshooting the problem.
The Logs Explorer view in GCP console is quite difficult to read as the trace is spread across at least 24 different dropdown views. I haven't been able to find a more reasonable log view.
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:357:73) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181) 
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78 
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

There is no message with a link to create an index. The last time this happened in April we fixed it by using the Firestore console to create a single field index:
collectionId: reports
fieldPath: generateDate
Collection group scope: Descending enabled


Late last week we deployed firestore.indexes.json with:
{
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "reports",
      "fieldPath": "generateDate",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        }
      ],
      "ttl": false
    }
  ],
  "indexes": []
}


This deployment seems to have broken the scheduled function even though this JSON was generated by the firebase CLI based on the project's indexes. We were under the impression that by setting this JSON, we would not have to go through this every time we deployed hosting.
Does anyone have any ideas as to why deploying hosting continually breaks this scheduled function, even though we have indexes set up that worked prior to deployment? Is firestore.indexes.json now conflicting with the single field index that was previously configured via the Firebase console?
Any help/direction is appreciated.

Which line of code generates the error?  Add some logging to better understand what this code is actually doing.  What else is in the error message?  If you do a web search for "firestore FAILED_PRECONDITION", you'll see that error messages typically come with more information.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

This is part of the problem. The logs are unreadable & broken into 24 groups in Logs Explorer. "Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION:
at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:357:73)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) . . ."

please check the reports ?you can simply add console log to do that ,inside and outside of for loop ,i think it will help us to locate the exact line .
